# Error when caching classes with (named) scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

This is a convoluted example so bear with me:

I have a script that I routinely use during dev that will wipe out my tables of my dev and test databases, remigrate, then reseed them.  Due to my use of triggers in a couple places, I've had to use rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test to migrate my test database properly.

Everything was fine until I turned config.cache_classes=true on in my test environment.  Then when the rake migration ran on an empty database I would get an error about how the table doesn't exist.  Running this with a --trace, I find that its blowing up on one of my objects when it declares a basic scope:

```
scope :find_by_route_and_date, lambda { |route_id, date|
    {
      :conditions=>{:route_id=>route_id, :schedule_date=>date}
    }
  }
```

The scope is in a lambda, so it shouldn't be getting evaluated, but the minute I remove cache_classes, the migration works fine.  So, to me it seems like its trying to cache the model, choking on the scope because the table doesn't exist yet, and never starting the migration.

Am I losing my mind?  Anyone else seen this?  If I need to wipe my db, do I need to turn caching off, then migrate, then turn it back on?

Rails 3.2, ruby 1.9.2, rake 0.9.2.2

**UPDATED:**

As requested, here is the stack trace: https://gist.github.com/1705064

The order.rb:179 is the place where my first scope is defined and where it blows up that I listed above.

Comment: what's the stacktrace you get?

Comment: edited to include the link to the trace on gist

Comment: i find it kinda strange that `order_controller.rb` is in the stack. sure you are not doing some crazy stuff in your rake tasks, that does actually call the scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interesting. My reading of the stack trace is that rails is trying to help you be seeing if whether creating that scope (ie creating a method of the same name) you would be creating trouble by overwriting some existing method.

This leads active record down `respond_to` where it thinks that your scope/method name looks a lot like a dynamic finder. It then goes further: as well as looking like a dynamic finder, do all the named attributes exist? This is where it tries to check what columns the non existant table has and everything blows up.

You could (I think) do one of a few things:

- before the scope, define a class method with the same name as the scope so as to short circuit the respond_to call (yuck)
- change your scope name
- override `valid_scope_name`

I'm still not sure why you can't setup the test db from a schema file, if necessary setting the schema dumper to `:sql` so that things that active record doesn't support natively are preserved.

Comment: You were dead on. I renamed the scope to not look like a finder and the migration ran fine.  I'll look into the sql dumper though, that would be a better solution for my triggers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally you shouldn't reference models at all in your migrations for a number of reasons. The most notable is that a lot of information about the table structure is cached when the model is instantiated the first time. The second most important issue is that the model file may not even exist in a future version of your app if it's refactored away.

A best practice is to always use more low-level methods of manipulating your data that will work regardless of the state of your `app/models` directory. A good migration suite can build from a pristine state to the most current version without getting hung up on missing files or methods. This is why being self-contained is important.

You can probably re-write this scope as a more literal thing that can be run with `execute`.

If you're using triggers and having trouble with the `test` environment because the schema dumper is not properly recording them, use the `:sql` format for your schema instead. This is a more literal copy and shouldn't be affected by the limitations of the Ruby-ized format.

Comment: My migrations aren't referring to the models.  This is happening before the migrations spin up at all.

Comment: From what I gather the model isn't being used in the migration (although I agree that is dangerous)

Comment: That is odd, then. Looks like you got a fix though!